# Manage files remotly with dotnet

Tags: vb.net, session

I write an application desktop (dot.net) that manage my files.
I want to run this application in my local network, and use a centred shared files repository in my server.

The issue is i can't open any files until i open manually the session between my pc and my server.

There is any way to automatically open this session with a code snippet ?

I am looking in the net but i can't find any clue!

my configuration :

1. I installed in my pc

   - Windows 7
   - Visual Studio 2008
   - .NET Framework 3.5
2. My server is windows server 2003

Thanks.

Comment: What is a "session"?

Comment: session = Is the administration session that i open it remotely from my laptop

Comment: i write my application in vb.net

Comment: Ask yourself: how could we possibly answer the question "is any way to automatically open this session with a code snippet" with such little information?  What is an *administrative session*?  Should we just guess?

Comment: @roryap I thank you for your interest in my question, sorry if i am not be clear enough.  i mean by administrative session is windows  session like in this picture https://i-technet.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC196885.gif

Comment: So you're setting up a document repository? Wouldn't it be easier to buy a SharePoint license or other off-the-shelf tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NET USE Z: \\server\share-folder` command to map a server share folder as a drive letter to your PC, and then you can use the .NET 'Process' class invoke the command.  After disk mapping, you can manage your remote file as local file.

Comment: This will fail if there is already a mapping using the Z:\ drive letter. In order to use the next available drive letter, omit the the `Z:` to be `net use \\server\share\someFolder`. you should compare the list of previous assigned drive letters to assigned drive letters after the command to get the new drive letter.  Also remember to unmap the drive upon application close because the mapping is a Windows thing and it will persist after the application

Answer (score 0):

Search in google for the Impersonate Library in .net this will let use use your domain user and impersonate in any computer using your windows credentials even if the current user doesn't has rigths to open the shared folder.